# How do we turn off automatic smart quotes/special character substitution?

Tags: character-encoding, editing

In Mathematica 8, whenever I enter "hello" into a cell of style "text", the quote marks are automatically converted to special characters:

`\[OpenCurlyDoubleQuote]hello\[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote]`

This automatic substitution does not happen in a cell of style "input" (good!).

Because I use Mathematica notebooks as a front-end to LaTeX, for me this substitution is a disaster, no matter where it occurs.

What is the preferred idiom for turning-off this smart-quote feature (and all similar automatic character substitution features) for all cells in a Notebook?

The ASCII characters that I type, are precisely the characters that I want in the notebook!

The Mathematica documentation is unhelpful ... or possibly I am not looking in the correct place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Option Inspector (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> O) look for `AutoQuoteCharacters` and set this on empty list. I presume you could set the same in the stylefile too.

Comment: Can also be set in the preferences.

Comment: @JohnSidles are you going to post that answer. It complements the others so you should.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Options[EvaluationNotebook[], CommonDefaultFormatTypes]
```

gives the default formatting:

> [image]

You can use `Options Inspector` to change the format type for `Text` from its default value `TextForm` to `StandardForm`:

[image]

To change the setting programmatically for the evaluation notebook, you can use:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CommonDefaultFormatTypes -> {"Text" -> StandardForm}]
```

Alternatively,

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, CommonDefaultFormatTypes -> {"Text" -> StandardForm}]
```

changes the setting for all new notebooks.

EDIT: You might want to explore related settings in the `Options Inspector`:

[image]

EDIT 2: I like Sjoerd's answer better. Here is the way to change this option setting programmatically:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], "AutoQuoteCharacters" -> {}]
```

or

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, "AutoQuoteCharacters" -> {}]
```

Comment: For me, all cells are "TextForm" (because my notebooks are a front-end for LaTeX).  Regrettably Mathematica 8 provides no documentation on this form. :(